# Access raw date values in Officejs add-in selection

Tags: javascript, office-js, excel-addins

I am trying to access values in Excel plugin via Officejs.

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(
    Office.CoercionType.Matrix,
    function(asyncResult => ...)
```

What I am looking for is an automatic way to access date values in their raw format without deduction if it is a date (initially, they are in Excel-like format, represented by a number of days after 01/01/1900).

Text of callback, but I can't find any interface to use so far.

`Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(zone, options, callback)` returns numbers in all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to get the value by using range.values API, then use setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy") to set it into time format.

Comment: I am basically searching for some unique way of getting dates in the raw format. Now if I use numberFormat on the cells that are formatted exactly like this format, it returns me a number (for valid dates) and a string (for dates before 1900). If I select a cell with different format, it breaks the value (does #### or a1995a, or kinda).